# what machine learning algorithms are good for mining various type of data at the same time?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I'm using python scikit-learn package so any demonstration using scikit learn function will be really appreciated :)

 Now I have several types of biomedical data: Clinical data(including treatment information and survival status), DNA methylation data, miRNA and RNA expression data. Each data type contains roughly 300 patient samples and 50-ish normal (control) samples. I want to use several machine learning algorithm to input these data together, and training a model so that it can predict the survival of a patient based on data given. That means, if we provide the clinical information, DNA methylation, miRNA and RNA expression of a patient, we can tell if the patient will die or can survive for some time (preferably, after applying certain targeted treatment).

Now I have some important questions:

1. Since the size of the samples are very different, how can I group these data and feed the algorithm? For instance, if do clustering, how can I align them?
[samples I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAaPn.png)

2. There are many probs for methylation, miRNA and RNA, over a thousand for each. Is there a way to filter out the important features(probs) and only train the model based on these data? Or even better, after training the model using all the data, can the model tell me which features are important among large amounts of features? Is scikit-learn preprocessing method enough to do this step?

If the question is confusing, here I came up with an example. Let's say if I can filter out some genes such that if the methylation level, miRNA or RNA level of one gene is detected abnormal, then we can say this patient is likey to be cured or died.

3. Is there a way to combine several algorithms together? For instance, using clustering to classify all features, and then input the results in random forest/PCA algorithms together get the model?

I haven't learned machine learning systematically, so I got really confused when trying to use them. I think I should use unsupervised algorithms. Is that correct?

Comment: This is all very vague and unclear. My impression is that you haven't understood your own questions yet.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm not native English speaker and also new to machine learning so sorry to make you feel confused. I tried to modify my question a little bit and hope you can understand it better now.

Comment: I think you mostly need to experiment some more and study some more to be able to pinpoint your question. Don't put multiple questions into one, that adds to the confusion. As for parts 1 and 3, an ensemble may be the answer.